# How can I disable chat heads?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, chat

My grandmother has a Motorola Droid Maxx 2 running Android 6.0.1 and she would like to disable chat heads entirely, for text messages and Messenger. A preliminary search through her notification settings, Google, and this site yielded no results. How can she do this?

Comment: In Messenger, click on your profile button on the top right. 

Scroll down to the "Chat Heads" setting and toggle it off.

Comment: Source for above (I don't use Facebook) http://mashable.com/2017/03/27/how-to-turn-off-chat-heads-messenger/#lZQjIPfMVmq1

Comment: For SMS , from the 3 dots menu turn off notifications

Comment: @beeshyams Where are these three dots?

Comment: In the screen where you see SMS, on the top right hand corner having SMS notifications.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a menu called "Advanced Features". Tap on that and then you will find something about smart pop-ups. Find the messaging app and disable it from there.

On my Samsung A50:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]